# Calculate scale & tilt from distance or points

Tags: java, math

Since I'm not the best in math, I'd like to **understand** how I can calculate a scale and tilting value from given variables.

> - zoom: A user places two fingers on the screen and moves them together/apart. The detector will report both the initial and current distance between fingers in pixels. Useful to implement camera zooming.
> - pinch: Similar to zoom. The detector will report the initial and current finger positions instead of the distance. Useful to implement camera zooming and more sophisticated gestures such as rotation.

My goal is to be able to pinch on a map and zoom in/out to/from the center of the map but as i'm zooming in to the center, the camera should tilt up and vice versa.

```
@Override
public boolean zoom (float originalDistance, float currentDistance){

   return false;
}

@Override
public boolean pinch (Vector2 initialFirstPointer, Vector2 initialSecondPointer, Vector2 firstPointer, Vector2 secondPointer){

   return false;
}
```

the following methods let me scale and tilt the map:

```
public boolean scaleMap(float scale, float pivotX, float pivotY) {}
public boolean setTilt(float tilt) {}
```

I'd like to scale and update my map accordingly, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
float yScale = (pointer2.y-initialPointer2.y)/pointer2.y;
changed = mViewport.scaleMap(yScale, 0, 0);
if (changed) {
    mMap.updateMap(true);
}
return changed;
```

**EDIT: Example of tilting while zooming in:**

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find zoom, you have to use the ratio of euclidean distances between fingers before and after zooming:

```
 dy = initialpointer2.y - initialpointer1.y
 dx = initialpointer2.x - initialpointer1.x
 new_dy = pointer2.y - pointer1.y
 new_dx = pointer2.x - pointer1.x

Scale = Math.sqrt((new_dy * new_dy + new_dx * new_dx) / (dy * dy + dx * dx))
```

If your math library contains `Hypot` function, use it:

```
Scale = Math.hypot(new_dy, new_dx) / Math.hypot(dy, dx)
```

To get rotation, calculate angle difference between finger-finger directions before and after:

```
 Dir = Math.atan2(dy, dx)
 New_Dir = Math.atan2(new_dy, new_dx)
 RotAngleRadians = New_Dir - Dir
```

Comment: This is great and really informative! Do you have an idea on how to calculate a tilt-based value based on your zooming in? I'd like my camera to tilt up slightly while zooming in while maintaining a focus point

Comment: I don't realize how camera could tilt up while central point stays the same

Comment: I misformed my question. I want to tilt my map up the more you zoom in. I have a function tiltMap(float move) that tilts the map based on a given value. I was wondering how I could calculate this value based on how much you are zoomed in

Comment: So you need to formulate some criteria for tilting. For example, your camera looks in the center of chessboard and sees 4 cells d4,d5,e4,e5. What should it see when you stretch fingers making 2x zoom?

Comment: I've updated my post with 2 pictures which showcases what I mean. Picture 1 is zoomed out. Picture 2 is zooming in which tilts the map so you can see some depth

Comment: OK, I saw such behavior is some products. In my opinion, they make tilting after some zoom level and limit tilt angle. Example: `if Zoom < 4 tilt = 0 else if Zoom < 16 then tilt = (zoom - 4) * 45/12 else tilt = 45`